# How can I get a character in a string by index?

Tags: c#, .net, string, indexof

I know that I can return the index of a particular character of a string with the `indexof()` function, but how can I return the character at a particular index?

Comment: I'm sure I'm missing something, but if you know the character to use when calling `indexof()` why do you then need to get it from the string? You could just return the character possibly using `indexof()` to prove it is in the string first.

Comment: ^ Yes, missing the ability to read. The OP didn't say s/he already has the character, or even anything close to that.

Comment: @MikeTwo The OP **doesn't** know the index of the character.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

```
string s = "hello";
char c = s[1];
// now c == 'e'
```

See also `Substring`, to return more than one character.

Answer (score 16):

Do you mean like this

```
int index = 2;
string s = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(s[index]);
```

string also implements `IEnumberable<char>` so you can also enumerate it like this

```
foreach (char c in s)
    Console.WriteLine(c);
```

Comment: How can I use your second option, (enumerating) but count the chars two at a time? e.g. "4567" will output to "45" first then "67" next. How would I do that? Thanks :)

Comment: @Momoro: `foreach (string substring in s.Chunk(2)) { ... }`. [Enumerable.Chunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) is built-in in .NET 6+, you can find example implementations for other versions here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12389203/87698