# use Linq to process groups of items in a list

Tags: c#, .net, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [LINQ Partition List into Lists of 8 members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773403/linq-partition-list-into-lists-of-8-members)
>   [how do I chunk an enumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389203/how-do-i-chunk-an-enumerable)

I have a list of many items, and a Method that works well on shorter lists of those same items.

Can I use LINQ to pull off N elements from the big list, and pass them into the Method, N at a time?  I'm sure there is an elegant way to to this without having to make an "int i=0;" variable.

Let me be clear, I know that foo.Take(10) will get me 10 items off the list.  But I need to keep processing the next set of 10, then the next set of 10 and so on.  The pseudo code should be something like:

```
var shortList = BigList.NiceMethod(10);
foreach (shorty in shortlist)
{
  Method(shorty);
}
```

This is probably some Group call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will give you a list of Lists where every List has at most N elements.

```
int N = 3;
List<int> list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

var ListOfLists = list.Select((x, inx) => new { Item = x, Group = inx / N })
                        .GroupBy(g => g.Group, g => g.Item)
                        .Select(x => x.ToList())
                        .ToList();
```

You can also use Morelinq's [Batch](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs?r=f85495b139a19bce7df2be98ad88754ba8932a28) method

```
var ListOfLists2 = list.Batch(3).Select(x => x.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Note the primary difference between this code an `Batch` is that batch is able to defer execution longer.  It only eagerly iterates a single batch at a time, not the whole sequence.

Comment: @Servy of course I know, but sometimes giving answers without materializing the query turns back as "it doesn't work". So I always give answers that way unless It is not explicitly mentioned in question.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass an `IEnumerable<T>` to your method and use [`Enumerable.Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx).

```
var part = items.Take(10);
method(part);
```

For the next part you could use `Skip`+`Take`:

```
var part = items.Skip(10).Take(10);
method(part);
```

Another option: use [`Enumerable.GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) with the remainder operator `%` to n packets:

```
int groupCount = 5;
var parts = items.GroupBy(i => i % groupCount);
foreach (var p in parts)
    method(p);
```

**Edit**: If you need to partition a sequence into smaller ones with the same size you can use this extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int batchSize)
{
    List<T> nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        nextbatch.Add(item);
        if (nextbatch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return nextbatch;
            nextbatch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }
    if (nextbatch.Count > 0)
        yield return nextbatch;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
    var l = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000).ToList<int>();
        int size = 11;
        var result = Enumerable.Range(0, l.Count / size + 1)
            .Select(p => l.Skip(p * size).Take(Math.Min(size, l.Count - size * p)).ToList())
            .Where(p=>p.Count > 0).ToList();
```

Comment: All good, but requires multiple enumeration of the source. While this not be a problem for a List, if the source enumerable is lazily evaluted, re-enumeration (required for the `.Skip` part of this code) might be costly/undesirable.