# Fetch 100 Records each time from a List c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have one list which has more than 2k records. I want that each time first 100 records must get fetched and next time next 100 records must be fetched and so on . I am using take method of list but it is giving me first 100  only every time. Below is my query:

```
task = dataAccessObjects.GetDataToArchive();
foreach(var rec in task)
{
  var f = task.Take(100);
}
```

Comment: huh, that `task` is hugely misleading.

Answer (score 7):

```
int i =0;
foreach(var rec in task)
{
  var f = task.Skip(i*100).Take(100);
  i++;
}
```

Use Skip function to skip already selected records

Comment: Readable but unfortunately not very efficient. You could use `Batch` from MoreLINQ. http://stackoverflow.com/a/11427448/284240

Comment: Thanks Akshey. Really appreciate your effort reply on my post. That worked.

Comment: @DarshanPatel: just look at the link ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter :  could you please paste alternative code for this?

Comment: @Rahul you are welcome. happy to help

Comment: @Rahul: this is a duplicate, but i have found another approach which i've posted some time ago which doesnt use Jon's `MoreLinq`(recommandable): [This `Batch`-extension method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13183592/284240) is more efficient than the `Skip...Take`-approach.

Comment: Or you could use [this method](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11775295/106159) which doesn't use any additional space (but which isn't threadsafe, if you care about that). But I'd say, whatever you do, don't use the very inefficient solution with Skip/Take above (use Tim's, Jon Skeet's or mine instead)