# How to split string after every n-th character?

Tags: c#, split

I have a string and I want to split the string after every 2nd comma.  Is this doable using split string in c#?

Example string:

```
"This,is,an, example,for,the,stackoverflow,community"
```

Desired output

```
This,is
an,example
for,the
stackoverflow,community
```

Any help would be much appreciated thanks!

Comment: No, you can either to this with a regex or a manually written loop. Split works on every instance of the character.

Comment: Did you mean: "This is, an example, for the, stackoverflow community" ? Because what you have is not every 2nd comma

Comment: @Heinzi They don't show an actual attempt to solve it themselves, thus likely down voted for lack of research.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Enumerable.Chunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-6.0) from .NET 6, you can

- split on `","`,
- create chunks of two items each and
- re-join those chunks:

```
string input = "This,is,an,example,for,the,stackoverflow,community";

var output = input.Split(",")
    .Chunk(2)
    .Select(chunk => string.Join(",", chunk));

foreach (string s in output)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

[fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ixqhbz)

If you're stuck with the "classic" .NET Framework, here are chunk implementations for .NET < 6:

- [how do I chunk an enumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12389203/87698)

Comment: Ow, nice. I didn't know of `Chuck`.

Comment: `Split(",")` will not work as there is no overload that only takes a string.  Instead use `Split(',')`

Comment: @juharr In .net 6 it will work.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan Oh they made the StringSplitOptions optional.

Comment: Thanks for the replies!  This solution works perfectly but unfortunately im running on .net core 3.1 so chunk wouldn’t work for me :/ chunk enumerable seems pretty complex for a split string. Would regex.split work ? I have tried to get the combination but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
var s = "This,is,an, example,for, the, stackoverflow, community";

var a = ("," + s + ",").Split(',');

//  requires using System.Linq;
var b = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length / 2)
        .Select(i => $"{a[2 * i]}, {a[2 * i + 1]}".Trim(',', ' '));
```

`Range` enumerates the resulting array and computes concatenations of the corresponding pairs of strings.

Comment: Maybe you want `var c = string.Join("\r\n", b);` in the end, or similar.

Comment: Agree with @JeppeStigNielsen: the output seems still wrong. I like the two-liner though.

Comment: See this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yqkw53

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a pattern to match 1 or more characters except for a comma using a negated character class `[^,]+` before and after the comma:

```
string pattern = @"[^,]+,[^,]+";
string input = "This,is,an, example,for,the,stackoverflow,community";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

Output

```
This,is
an, example
for,the
stackoverflow,community
```