# Split concurrentbag to 2D list in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to split a concurentBag in 2D list of specific length.

Current code I am using. Here the bag can be of any length between 1 - 1000.

```
 private static readonly ConcurrentBag<object> bag = new();

    public static void updateResult()
    {
        var i = bag.GetEnumerator();
        var tempL = 100;
        List<List<object>> data = new();
        List<object> temp = new();
        while (i.MoveNext()) {
            tempL -= 1;
            if (tempL > 0)
            {
                temp.Add(i.Current);
            }
            else
            {
                data.Add(temp);
                temp.Clear();
                tempL = 100;
            }
        }
        if(temp.Count > 0)
        {
            data.Add(temp);
        }
}
```

Hoping to optimize the code or any inbuilt method that can replace this messy code

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Also, I have a feeling your code doesn't actually work since you only new up `temp` once and not once per loop.

Comment: @DavidG the version is net6.0 and for the new every time I can use it, I haven't executed the code just wrote the logic.
temp.clrear() can be replaced for temp = new(); if clear does not work

Comment: `temp.clear` wouldn't help either since you are just re-adding the same instance to the list every time.

Comment: okay temp = new(); every iteration  works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use [Enumerable.Chunk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.chunk?view=net-7.0) if you are using .Net 6, otherwise it is not [very difficult to write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389203/how-do-i-chunk-an-enumerable).

```
List<object[]> chunks = bag.Chunk(100).ToList();
```

> Hoping to optimize the code

Optimize for *what*? Runtime? Readability?

Note that this produces a jagged array/list. If you want to represent a 2D *grid* you are better of using a multidimensional array `object[,]` or create your own wrapper around a 1D array that trivializes the problem:

```
public class My2DArray<T>{
    public T[] Data {get; }
    public int Width { get; }
    public int Height { get; } // this could be derived from the width & array length
    public T this[int x, int y]
        {
            get => Data[y * Width + x];
            set => Data[y * Width + x] = value;
        }
}
```

Note that this makes no difference if the source is a `ConcurrentBag` or a `IEnumerable`. If the concurrentBag changes concurrently with this code, values might or might not be included.

Comment: The reason I asked what version of .NET was to check if `Chunk` was available since it was only introduced in .NET 6. Definitely worth being a little cautious before adding answers like this without knowing beforehand.

Comment: @DavidG Fair point, I added a link to "how do I chunk an enumerable?"