# Is there a way to access the character of a string in a string array in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string array, I want to access the characters of the first element in that array:

```
string[] str= new string[num];

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    str[i] = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

To access the characters of the first element in the string array, in Java

```
str[0].CharAt[0] // 1st character
```

Is there a way in C# for this? The only function I could see was use of `substring`. It will incur more overhead in such case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to return the character which is at the index?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416894/how-to-return-the-character-which-is-at-the-index)

Comment: @Rinktacular: "which will print out one character at a time" - nope, because `str` is an *array of* strings, not a single string.

Comment: Oops.. good catch.  Misread the Declaration. :)

Comment: @Rintacular  this doesn't solve, I want to access character of a string in the array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would use:

```
str[0][0]
```

where the first `[0]` is accessing the 0th array member, while the next `[0]` is [the ***indexer***](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars.aspx) defined by `System.String` which gives the 0th `char` value (UTF-16 code unit) of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that:

```
string[] s = new string[]{"something", "somethingMore"};
char c = s[0][0];
```

Comment: What's the downvote on this answer for? It surely answers the question, even if the example is not directly copy-and-pasteable into the OP's code.

Comment: This satisfies the question.  Not sure why it is down voted.

Comment: Didn't downvote, but it doesn't answer the question. The question is about the characters inside a string inside an array. Your answer is just the characters inside the string. You're missing the array part.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the first string of the string array to a character array and simply get the first value of the character array.

```
string[] stringArray = {"abc"};
char[] charArray = stringArray[0].ToCharArray();
char first = charArray[0];
```

Comment: There is no need to copy the entire string contents over into a new array if you just want the first `char`.

Comment: Why make this into a char array?

Comment: I didn't know you could index on a string like the other answers show. Thanks!