# How to verify the third character of a textBox.Text

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, textbox

In *short*, something like this:

```
private void checkMethod()
{
    if (textBoxCode.Text.Contains("a").Position(Char.3)))
    {
        // Then do this...
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get a character in a string by index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416894/how-can-i-get-a-character-in-a-string-by-index)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your pseudo code completely. There are many ways, however I guess you could do something like

```
if(textBoxCode.Text?.Length >= 3 && textBoxCode.Text[2] == 'a')
```

<sub>*Calling `textBoxCode.Text?.Length` is basic fault tolerance*</sub>

---

Or you could use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.elementatordefault?view=netcore-3.1), which does all the above

> Returns the element at a specified index in a sequence or a default
> value if the index is out of range.

```
if(textBoxCode.Text?.ElementAtOrDefault(2) == 'a')
```